# Html + Css написать html код

Tags: html, jquery, css

Всем привет, читаю учебник по JQuery для начинающих и наткнулся на вопрос для проверки знаний.
Нужно написать HTML для данного стиля.

```
#my p.announce, .tt.pm li li a:hover+span { color: #f00; }
```

Понятно, что вначале должно быть как-то так:

```
<div id=my>
    <p class=announce><H2 class= "tt pm">
         <ul><li><ul><li>BLAH<li></li></ul></ul>
```

Но вот что дальше, понять не могу. Подскажите пожалуйста как бы сделали это вы.

Comment: Читайте https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.B2.D0.B8.D0.BB.D0.B0_.D0.BF.D0.BE.D1.81.D1.82.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.8F_CSS

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Не забывайте закрывать теги. a:hover + span - означает следующий span после элемента a при наведенном на него курсоре.

```
 <div id=my>
        <p class=announce>
            Текст
            <ul class="tt pm">
                <li>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Ссылка</a>
                            <span>Текст при наведении на ссылку</span>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Один из вариантов как это может выглядеть, без лишних элементов.

```
<div id="my">
    <p class="announce">Announce</p>    
</div>

<ul class="tt pm">
    <li>
        <ul><li><a href="#">Навести</a> <span>Подсветить</span></li></ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/91f3z4uu/